# How many entities in an area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make it so I always have 50 entities in an area. So when 1 dies/despawns/leaves the area I want it to detect that and summon in a new entity, and yes I do want them to die/despawn/leave the area so preventing those things is not an option.

Comment: @RudolfLibal People are editing to make content more useful and searchable for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug a redstone clock into 2 Command blocks (or use 1.9 Repeat command blocks):

The first command:

```
/testfor @e[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
```

And the second:

```
/testforblock X Y Z command_block 1 {SuccessCount:49}
```

Place a Comparator leading from the second Command Block - that is, if there are 49 entities, it succeeds. Then place your final command block next to the Comparator, into it put your `/summon` command.

Comment: What happens, if two or more entities die at same time - between RS clock tick? Then it will be broken.

Comment: Thankyou for the easy to read and understand answer. this is good enough if not plenty good for what I need it for!

Comment: @RudolfLibal I did not downvote your answer, which you should *know*
 because there are no downvotes on this answer (and you didn't lose rep). I did not provide an answer myself because I wanted to give you the chance to [edit] yours, since the differences to your answer would be fairly minor, although the impact on the game performance would be significant.

Comment: That said, downvotes are part of how this site works, and you, as a user of this site, will have to accept this. While providing an alternative answer would be ideal, it is not a necessity or even prerequisite for downvoting. The only thing any user of this sites needs to legitimately downvote an answer is to find it "not useful".

Comment: Take a look at what the downvote privilege page says: `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`  If someone has made no effort, **downvote**.  There's lots of that going around here, so that's why we have downvotes.  They are arguably the best tool we have for site curation.

Comment: @Rudolf You haven't seen the amount of crap we have to deal with. That's all been deleted, but the votes remain. Either way, you need to learn what SE is all about. Downvotes are *important*. More important than almost anything else you do.

Comment: @Rudolf You don't have to. You just have to stop telling people how to vote. You vote your way, we vote ours, and all is good. Telling someone they're doing it wrong is going to get you nothing but backlash. Especially for downvotes.

Comment: Yes it is okay. It's also okay to downvote whatever I want. I do what I want, you do what you want, and we're all good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stats`

```
    stats block [K] set SuccessCount #Fake K
[K]:testfor @e
    scoreboard players test #Fake K 0 49
CONDxxxx
```